# Any idea what this is?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, laundry

We have this in the washer dryer area of our Mother-In-Law. When we moved in no washer dryer was present. I sort of suspect it's some sort of drain hookup because there is no drain. Does anyone know?

[image: what is this? It's 2 inches off the ground.]

Can't make out text clearly
[image: heads on]

Drain on water hookup is sealed. 
[image: water hookup - drain port is sealed]

Comment: Can you give us a head-on photo of it?

Comment: @threephaseeel Added

Comment: The drain could still be in there though.

Comment: There should be a drain under the cover between the hot and cold water hookups. The square thing is the end of a clean-out cap for the drain (I'm guessing it's below the other stuff).

Comment: A stand pipe may have been planned here. Turn the threaded cap out. Fit a male adaptor in and elbow upward add pipe to proper height then slip washer drain hose into it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a drain clean out port.

Do you have a hookup to water for a washer? How about a vent for the dryer? The cap looks like it's been pushed in after the painting took place. Did you try to remove it? It could be a cleanout cover plugging a dryer vent...

Answer (score 1):

Is this object on the ceiling or wall? If it was on the ceiling, I’d figure it is a smoke detector. However, I’m guessing that it is on the wall, thus I think that it might be an old drain or pipe of some sort. There might be a professional that could tell you more.

Answer (score 1):

That is a threaded pipe cap. Most likely it could be used as a drain for the washer.

Unscrew the cap using a large pipe wrench. Install a male adaptor into the threaded opening then plumb a proper stand pipe drain with a p trap.

[image]